# Sending Image in post request Python "message":"File not present in request."

Tags: python, python-requests

everytime I send a post request to an api (https://publish.roblox.com/v1/games/gameidhere/thumbnail/image) I get this

[image: error]

```
{"code":2,"message":"File not present in request.","userFacingMessage":"Something went wrong"}
```

my code

```
def setgameproperties(uid,pid):
 mytoken = getauth()
 head = {
        'x-csrf-token' : mytoken,
        'user-agent' : 'Roblox/WinInet',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie' : '.ROBLOSECURITY=' + cookie + ";",
 }    
 imagedata = {'files': open('thumbnail.png', 'rb')}
 q = requests.post('https://publish.roblox.com/v1/games/' +uid+ '/thumbnail/image',headers=head,files=imagedata)
 print("SETTING GAME ICON: " + str(q.content))
```

The payload that is supposed to be sent

[image]

am I sending the image wrong?

Comment: Does it want the name to be `request.files`?

Comment: Setting the name to request.files didn't work, I get the same error